# Java getter not working?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Ok so i have a comboBox, and a JTextField, whenever i chose the quantity, it would be displayed on the textfield. I have another class, which will retrieve the whatever inside the textfield, but the order class doesn't retrieve the information from catalogue class.

```
class Catalogue extends JPanel {

    String[] h1Quantity = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
    h1CBox = new JComboBox <String> (h1Quantity);
    h1CBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
    h1CBox.addActionListener (new Listener());
    h1CBox.setPreferredSize ( new Dimension (50,30));


    JLabel noBooks = new JLabel ("Quantity");

    booksF = new JTextField(8);


public class Listener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {            
            int total = h1CBox.getSelectedIndex();
            booksF.setText(Integer.toString(total));
        }
}


public String booksFText() {
       return booksF.getText();
    }
}


class Order extends JPanel {


   Catalogue catalogue ;

   public Order (Catalogue catalogue)
   {
      this.catalogue = catalogue; 

     JPanel panel = new JPanel (); 
     String text2= catalogue.booksFText();
     textArea1 = new JTextArea (text2, 20, 35);
     add(textArea1);
     add(panel); 
   }

}
```

I'm new to java so please keep it simple. thanks alot.

Comment: Include the stack trace of the exception in your question.

Comment: Where are you getting a null pointer? Have you tried writing a test and debugging it?

Comment: Java has a excellent exception "traceback" mechanism which points you directly at the error location.  Learn to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 constructors in the `Order` class and `catalogue` is only set in the first one. Set this in the second contructor as well and the NPE should go away (although hard to know for sure without the stacktrace!)

Comment: this is the only thing that I can think of as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Always try to post complete code. and stack trace too.**

See your order class.

```
class Order extends JPanel {

   public Order (Catalogue catalogue)
   {
     add(textArea);
   }

}
```

If you use the second constructor , then the class variable catalogue will not be given memory. Thus NULL POINTER EXCEPTION . The code inside the second constructor has been moved to the first one.

The other reason may be that the variable being passed in order constructor is not defined properly. Should be done something like this.

```
Catalogue catalogue = new Catalogue();
Order order = new Order(catalogue);
```

See Updated Catalogue class.

```
class Catalogue extends JPanel {

    String[] h1Quantity = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
    JComboBox<String> h1CBox ;  //Assuming you forgot to define it.
    JLabel noBooks ;
    JTextField booksF ;


    //Define a new constructor
    public Catalogue () {

      //set jlabel 
      noBooks = new JLabel ("Quantity");      

      //set combobox
      h1CBox = new JComboBox <String> (h1Quantity);
      h1CBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
      h1CBox.addActionListener (new Listener());
      h1CBox.setPreferredSize ( new Dimension (50,30));

      //set textfield 
      booksF = new JTextField(8);  

      //add UI items to your panel class
      add(h1CBox); //combobox
      add(noBooks); // label
      add(booksF); // textfield
    }


public class Listener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {            
            int total = h1CBox.getSelectedIndex();
            booksF.setText(Integer.toString(total));
        }
}


public String booksFText() {
       return booksF.getText();
    }
}
```

Always define your UI like this . Of course , there are better ways . Thus code looks clean and you understand things. Learn to put comments to remind you what you tried to do somewhere.

The MAIN Class

```
public class Main {
  static JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(40,40);

  static class Order extends JPanel{
     public Order(){
        add(textArea);
     }
  }

  static class Catalogue extends JPanel{
    ....

    private ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
              textArea.setText(h1CBox.getSelectedIndex()+"");
       }
    }; 
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
    //Construct a frame and add panels and you are good to go.
  }

}
```

One last suggestion, if you plan on NOT changing the data of textarea yourself , use textfield or label instead of textarea. Sometimes the text inside textarea is set , but user is unable to see because of improper bounds . So , to be sure just replace the textarea with label or textfield. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks. it solved the null pointer exception but the info doesn't get passed into the second class though.

Comment: Thanks for replying, i did everything you said but it still doesn't appear.

Comment: Ohk, now I get it. When you are passing the Panel ie Catalogue , only the panel gets copied , the values inside its UI items are not copied along with it. So instead of Catalogue object inside constructor , you can directly pass the data. ie Order order = new Order(catalogue.booksFText()); Remember to change the datatype in your order class and use it directly in your textarea.

Comment: Is Order panel being formed at runtime ? If not , setting the textarea inside constructor won't work . Otherwise you can use textarea inside the catalogue class only and set the values at runtime using _area.setText(textfield.getText());_

Comment: It still doesn't work! nothing displayed. i tried using booksFText() in the catalogue class but still nothing displayed.

Comment: I guess you cannot achieve it passing references like this. You must use a shared variable . The textarea (which is a part of Order is updated by Combobox in Catalogue) . So make textarea a global variable. Add it to Order and Update it in listener of combobox . This will definitely work . See updated code.

Comment: Don't forget to choose this as correct answer if it helped you. and You are welcome. :)

Comment: what if i need it to be String? textField.getText() doesnt work

Comment: If you want it to be String , simply do this **textfield.getText()+""**

Comment: yup i tried. i did something like String text2 = Global.title.getText() + "test"; it doesn't work. only test gets printed out.

Comment: well , this means that either title doesn't contain any string or Globa l is not working as we want it to work. Did you try the code as specified above in my answer ? It should work . Can you post more lines of your code ?

Comment: yup i did. it's ok you helped me alot. guess i'll try to figure it myself instead of waiting for others to spoonfeed me. thanks again!

Comment: Well , as you wish. Best of luck.